# Replace PHP imprimir corretamente

Tags: php

Sou iniciante em PHP e preciso criar uma função que reescreva o texto mascarando o CPF.

Eu, Fulano, CPF 123.234.345/56,
casado com Beltrana, CPF 234.345.456/67,
gostaria de solicitar o registro do imóvel adquirido
de Sicrano, CPF 345.456.567/78.

Virar

Eu, Fulano, CPF xxx, casado com Beltrana, CPF xxx, gostaria de
solicitar o registro do imóvel adquirido de Sicrano, CPF xxx.

Criei a seguinte função:

```
<?php

$texto = "Eu, Fulano, CPF 123.234.345/56, 
casado com Beltrana, CPF 234.345.456/67, 
gostaria de solicitar o registro do imóvel adquirido 
de Sicrano, CPF 345.456.567/78.";

function reescreverCpfs($texto)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^@\s]*.[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/',
        'xxx',
        $texto);
}
echo reescreverCpfs($texto);
```

Mas ela está imprimindo o seguinte:

Eu, Fulano, xxx
casado com Beltrana, xxx
gostaria de solicitar o registro do imóvel adquirido
de Sicrano, xxx

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi a duvida corretamente, mas acho que um melhor REGEX seria algo como:

```
/\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}\/\d{2}/
```

Isso seria: {3 Dígitos}.{3 Dígitos}.{3 Dígitos}/{2 Dígitos}, o que é o formato de `123.234.345/56`.

---

```
<?php

$texto = "Eu, Fulano, CPF 123.234.345/56, casado com Beltrana, CPF 234.345.456/67, gostaria de solicitar o registro do imóvel adquirido de Sicrano, CPF 345.456.567/78.";

function reescreverCpfs($texto) {
    // Só mudou o regex para o mencionado acima:
    return preg_replace('/\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}\/\d{2}/', 'xxx', $texto);
}

echo reescreverCpfs($texto);
```

Resultado:

```
Eu, Fulano, CPF xxx, casado com Beltrana, CPF xxx, gostaria de solicitar o registro do imóvel adquirido de Sicrano, CPF xxx.
```